# Treating old cedar?

Tags: bathtub, wood-finish, water-treatment

I just moved into a home with an interesting master bath. The back shower wall and the vanity are made entirely from rough red cedar.  It looks good and has minimal wear so far. Some soap scum and It looks like the wood has been slightly bleached, most likely from a combination of sunlight and alkaline stuff resting on the counter. My question is, how long can I expect this to stand up to bathroom wear and tear and should I be treating it at some point?

Comment: I am a big fan of cedar. When you say the shower back wall, do you mean the back side of the shower wall? Is the interior of the shower the usual water impervious surface, i.e., tile or equivalent?

Comment: No. The shower is roughly 4x5 feet with the back wall, and a seat being made of cedar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both cedar and redwood last for many years, redwood longer, soap scrum , chlorine and many other chemicals really are not a problem. I have replaced septic tanks that were both Cedar and redwood that were 40 to 80 years old with redwood being the longer lasting so I doubt there would be a problem unless there is a fungus or mold growing on it. Today cedar is the leading natural wood. Because of cost for fencing it just turns gray and lasts for years even decades with no treatment, stain or paint at all.